# Plot mathematical relations like a circle with equation x^2+y^2=c^2

Tags: android, achartengine, mpandroidchart

I want to use to "mpandroidchart" library to plot mathematical functions and relations. 
Can it be used to plot a circle and other relations ?
I am using Acharengine to plot functions but , Achartengine doesn't have support to plot relations (one to many). So I want to ask if it is possible with this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, plotting mathematical functions and relations with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) is not supported at the moment.

Nevertheless, I am considering to add this feature at some point in the future.

Comment: This is best looking charting library around. I really want to migrate over to this library from Achartengine for my app. Can you share some rough timeline when we can expect this feature ?

Comment: meeting same problem. need draw parabol chart or curve with offset